# Mathematics of Marxian Economics

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics, marxism

I have studied some Marxian economics, and realise that Marx's writings were not very mathematical. I recently came to know of Analytical Marxism and Neo-Marxian economics. I read the Wikipedia page on the Feldman- Mahalanobis model and also a short article by Samuelson.

What are some good books or other resources to study mathematical models based on Marxian economics, say, that were developed in Analytical Marxism or Neo-Marxian Economics or any other field?

Comment: My Youtube channel has some resources. Paul cockshott Channel has some material but hes more into historical materialism so you got to really look around for what you need. His video on Okishios theorem is put together nicely.

Answer (score 3):

*Value, Competition and Exploitation* by Cogliano, Flaschel, Franke, Fröhlich and Veneziani, *Classical Political Economics and Modern Capitalism* by Tsoulfidis and Tsaliki provide formalizations of classical/Marxian approach, you can find them on libgen.